# Identify this figure - soccer shirt with a "VS" (or cut off "US") logo with soccer ball (football) on front, and "7" on back

Tags: minifigure-identification

Checked lots of different categories on BrickLink, but couldn't find anything on this figure, or even the torso by itself. Any help to get me closer to figuring out who this little guy is would be much appreciated!

[image: minifig front]
[image: minifig back]

Comment: My first guess would be that some fan of a sports team printed out its logo (or cut it out from a magazine or similar) and glued it onto a minifigure.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but the 'stickers' are very similar to the type used in that era of minifigure (where the stickers put on torsos were often the type that would crack and peel with age).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Soccer Player White Team Player 5

[image]

This [minifigure](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=soc075#T=I) appeared only once in the [2002 set Grand Championship Cup - U.S. Men's Team Cup Edition (3425)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=3425-1#T=I).

[image]

There are two sticker sheets included in the set ([1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3425stk01&#T=C&C=0), [2](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3425stk02&#T=C&C=0)), the second sticker sheet shows the stickers used on the minifigures. However the sticker used is for player number 7, but BrickLink calls this minifig player 5 (which isn't a huge difference but possibly worth mentioning for identification).

The [instructions](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/3425/US_National_Team_Cup_Edition_Set) don't provide any particular guidance as to which minifigure is which number, probably because none of them represent real football players. You probably couldn't find the exact Minifig on Bricklink because they use an image without the stickers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the informational and insightful answer! I figured it was one of those figures that isn't listed with sticker information (there are also some parts with that issue, especially in older sets with smaller 'sticker over assembly' builds). Anyway, now I know where he came from, much appreciated!

Comment: The "VS" is actually "US" and that is the logo used by US Soccer from 1995 to 2006. See history of crest logos here: https://news.sportslogos.net/2016/02/29/us-soccer-officially-unveils-new-crest/